# Multicycle Path

Tags: digital-logic

Can someone please explain this diagram and the waveform to me? I understand the jist of a multicycle path but this waveform just isn’t making sense to me for some reason. If we want the receiving flop to receive the new signal every 3 cycles, how is this ensuring that and can someone explain the waveform diagrams to me in more detail?

[image]

Image: [source](https://vlsiuniverse.blogspot.com/2014/07/multicycle-paths-sta.html?m=1)

Answer (score 2):

> If we want the receiving flop to receive the new signal every 3 cycles, how is this ensuring that

The diagram shown doesn't ensure that. What provides this is whatever circuit is generating the "Enable" signal. If it was a clock with half the frequency, it could simply be a DFF with its inverted output connected to the input. For division by 3, a shift register is a simple choice, like in the example below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. My confusion arises from the waveform for the enable signal. I don’t understand why the setup check is being performed from the 1st clock cycle and not the 0th. Isn’t enable high on the 0th cycle?